# YoY comparison using QlikView

Tags: qlikview

My data contains daily data from last March till now. I want to compare the sales amount of 2015/4 vs 2014/4 and 2015/4 vs 2015/3.

My date format is 01,02,03,04,...,12 for `Date_Month`, and 2014,2015 for `Date_Year`.

I first create two variables:

```
vCurrentYear=max(Date_Year)
vCurrentMonth=Max (Date_Month)
```

Then I create a bar chart and my expressions are as below:

```
Last Year:

Sum({<[Date_Year]={$(=(vCurrentYear)-1)}Date_Month={"<=$(vCurrentMonth)"}>}[SALES_AMOUNT])

Current Year:

Sum({<[Date_Year]={$(vCurrentYear)},Date_Month={"<=$(vCurrentMonth)"}>}SALES_AMOUNT)
```

But the result is only adding two years together.... not comparing the two years. The graph link is as below:

http://www.2shared.com/photo/xlG-XpI7/yoy.html

I want a bar chart with two different bars for different years, the x axis is Date_Month.

I am using QlikView 11.20.12664.0 SR9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, ensure that you add your `Date_Month` field as a dimension in your chart:

[image: A view of the dimension tab of the chart properties]

The left chart in the image below shows the result if you do not add `Date_Month` as a dimension, the right chart shows the result after adding it:

[image: A comparison of charts]

**Edit**:
It looks like your "Last Year" expression is incorrect, you're missing a comma between `[Date_Year]={$(=(vCurrentYear)-1)}` and `Date_Month={"<=$(vCurrentMonth)"}`, i.e.:

```
Sum({<[Date_Year]={$(=(vCurrentYear)-1)}, Date_Month={"<=$(vCurrentMonth)"}>}[SALES_AMOUNT])
```

**Edit 2**
Also, ensure that your variables are defined in the "Variable Overview" dialogue rather than in your script:

[image: The Variable Overview dialogue]

**Edit 3**
One other thing to check is that the field names that you're referring to in your Set Analysis expressions are the same as those that are in your data that is loaded into QV.

In your source data, you have `DATE_MONTH` and `DATE_YEAR`, however, in your expressions (and variables) in your question, you have `Date_Year` and `Date_Month`. Fields in QV are **case-sensitive**, so as a result, your expressions will not calculate correctly.

In this case, based on your source data, I would recommend changing your variables and fields to the following:

*Variables*:

```
vCurrentYear = max(DATE_YEAR)
vCurrentMonth = max(DATE_MONTH)
```

*Expressions*:

```
sum({<DATE_YEAR={$(=(vCurrentYear)-1)}, DATE_MONTH={"<=$(vCurrentMonth)"}>} SALES_AMOUNT)

sum({<DATE_YEAR={$(vCurrentYear)}, DATE_MONTH={"<=$(vCurrentMonth)"}>} SALES_AMOUNT)
```

Comment: I had added dimension Date_Month, but the graph showed like this :http://www.2shared.com/photo/xlG-XpI7/yoy.html

Comment: @RoseShen Looks like one of your expressions may be incorrect, have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it looks better! but there's one thing....that it adds 2014/4 and 2015/4 together, so the two bars are the same...http://www.2shared.com/photo/bqE81QHS/yoy2.html...

Comment: Looks to me like the variables are not being evaluated correctly in your expressions, have updated my answer. HTH

Comment: I already set the variables in the "Variable Overview". Here's the link of my data: http://www.2shared.com/file/Pcqc2kZS/TT_FY2014_FA_DATABASE-rev.html?
Maybe you can tell what's wrong in my expression if you have database. THX

Comment: Thank you for that - helped me find the issue. Fields in QV are case-sensitive: your source data had different field names versus your expressions (e.g. `DATE_MONTH` versus `Date_Month`).

Comment: Thanks very much!! Now the graph shows exactly what I want! thank you so much!